# Making dependencies available to an instance which is not created by DI framework

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.5 with Guice for DI and I have below requirement.

There are some classes under the package com.job and we used to find all the classes under this package using reflection and initialize them using .newInstance method of class Class.

The classes under com.job are dependent upon some other classes such class MarkService.java and TableService.java and these classes had all the static methods which we used directly from the classes under com.job

Now the static methods from the classes MarkService.java and TableService.java have been converted into non-static methods and other classes that were referring these methods have been modified to use non-static methods by injecting instances of MarkService.java and TableService.java into classes using it. The DI is fine with the classes that are not created by .newInstance method such as Controllers.

Now the classes under com.job whose instances are created using .newInstance method, we wanted instances of MarkService and TableService to be auto injected into instances of classes under com.job

Need your help in identifying how this can be achieved.

Thank You

Comment: Any inputs on this?